# appending values from list to append at the edit text

Tags: java, android

i have a friend list from facebook and above the list ,there is edit text box.

i able to retrieve the name from the list .

When i click on the one position from the list ,i want to show that name to the edit text,then if other name is selected ,then it added to the edit text box after first selected name and so on.

I had tried finding the way of doing this ,but could not able to get the proper answer for implementing this .

added the name to the list which is being selected by the user.

**for example**

below is the list and above is the edit text when i click on the list view position,the

value of that particular position to be shown in the edit text,now if other position is

clicked by the user ,in the edit text ,it will be shown as name1,name2.

if third value is selected from the list then i should be shown as name1,name2,name3 
and so on.

When i am trying to add in the array list,on clicking ,it overwrite the previous value and shown only one  value in the edit text.

Regards
inder

Comment: Use [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) Example : [Demo](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-multiautocompletetextview.html) [Demo1](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiautocompletetextview.html)

Comment: Easier to help if you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/chips-text-fields), this is a beautiful solution for you to use in your code